# when I run this code in Pycharm i didn't get any outputs simply it shows------ process finished with exit code 0. please help me with this issue

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch

```
import torch
torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.current_device()
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
torch.cuda.memory_reserved()
torch.cuda.memory_allocated()
torch.cuda.memory_allocated()
var1=torch.FloatTensor([1.0,2.0,3.0]).cuda()
var1
var1.device
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
df.head()
df.isnull().sum()
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
df['Outcome']=np.where(df['Outcome']==1,"Diabetic","No Diabetic")
df.head()
sns.pairplot(df,hue="Outcome")
```

The output shows:
C:\Users\vinot.conda\envs\python21\python.exe D:/python/python_work/pythonProject/diabetes.py

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `print` your outputs, for example:

```
torch.cuda.is_available()
```

Will return either `True`/`False` but it isn't assigned to any variable and hence it does nothing. It doesn't work like Jupyter notebooks.

You can assign your outputs to `variable`, just like you did with

```
df=pd.read_csv('diabetes.csv')
```

Or you can print `dataframe` (or any other variable that is not assigned for that matter, not sure what you're after):

```
print(df.head())
```